# Ngnix Rewrite - If URL contains

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, url, regex

I'm having a small issue - my error log is filling up with requests to a directory folder on my site (but with added data that shouldn't be there).

```
http://example.com/the-directory/undefined
http://example.com/the-directory/administrator
http://example.com/the-directory/admin
http://example.com/the-directory/script
```

How can setup a rewrite so any requests that contains :

```
/the-directory/{any extra data}
```

301 redirects to

```
/the-directory/
```

What I have tried is :

```
rewrite ^/the-directory/(.*)$ /the-directory/ last;
```

But that just gets stuck in a redirect loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If these are not legitimate requests, you should probably just continue sending the 404 error.

Comment: those are just some examples - some are legit requests (which appears to be a typo in the link to my site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
rewrite ^/the-directory/.+$ /the-directory/ permanent;
```

You stuck in a redirect loop because regex `^/the-directory/(.*)$` matches `/the-directory/`.